# Pre-index page before entering the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the following effect, when a person comes to a domain, he sees the brand logo, language options and a big text that says enter. When the user presses enter he is redirected to the index file.

What would be the best way to make this?

Comment: Don't do that. Splash screens were invented to make it look like something was happening when a large application was loading on a slow computer. Putting an interstitial page like that up is nothing more than a waste of your visitors' time.

Comment: The index file is the first page he lands on, in your case the one with the brand logo. So you would redirect them to another page with a normal link. (Side comment: Quentin is right, people might see it as a waste of time).

Comment: There is a good reason behind it. :)

Comment: You could always create the splash screen with fixed position and a higher z-index, then hide it onclick - then at least (if you must use it) the transition will be quicker.